# Collapse hidden UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

In my code I hide various UIButtons on my page using UIButton.hidden if the data source for that button does not contain a value.

For example a business may or may not have a URL.  In my app, if a business has a website, I load it into the title of a button so the use can click on the button and be taken to the business' website.  If the business does not have a website, I hide the button.

The challenge is that the button appears to take up screen real-estate even when it is hidden.  I have even tried the following code and the button still consumes space on the page:

```
btnURL.frame.size.height = 0
btnURL.frame.size.width = 0
btnURL.setTitle("", forState: .Normal)
btnURL.hidden = true
```

Any suggestions on how to get the button to not consume space on the screen?  I don't want to remove it because there are several other buttons and labels that have constraints dependent on this button.

Comment: change the button's width (or height) to `0` and update the constraints (if you are using auto-layout).

Comment: have you tried call self.layoutIfNeeded() ?

Comment: hoelx - I have already done the height / width  thing (please see the code I posted) and that does not work by itself.  What constraints do I need to update?  I created all the constraints in IB and change the width or height of the button should not require and update to the constraints as far as I can tell.  Please let me know.

Comment: iamdavidiam - I added this line of code before the hidden = true line of code and it did not seem to have any affect.  btnURL.layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: Do all your buttons have the same height (assuming the buttons are stacked vertically)? If they do, or you can make them so, there is a fairly easy way to do this, otherwise I think it would be pretty difficult if you want to be able to remove any of several buttons in any combination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, I add button width constrain and set it to zero:

```
btnURLWidth.constant = 0
```

P.S. To hide label you can set zero font.

```
[UIFont systemFontOfSize:0]
```

Comment: I used these three lines of code and the space on the page went away.  I was only concerned about the height of the button so I did not implement anything regarding the width.                        btnURL.titleLabel?.text = ""
            btnURL.titleLabel?.font = btnURL.titleLabel!.font.fontWithSize(0)
            btnURL.hidden = true